# Monitor SQL statements in DB2

Tags: db2

I need to monitor SQL statements issued to DB2 database. I found the following article http://www.dba-db2.com/2010/01/trace-sql-statements-in-db2-database.html and I can to indeed capture SQL statements.

The problem is that prepared SQL statements still hold question marks. It there a way to get the final version of SQL statements?

DB2 version: 10.1.3

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think, that I found the solution http://db2commerce.com/2013/12/03/using-an-event-monitor-to-capture-statements-with-values-for-parameter-markers/ *(this link isn't working anymore. Use archive.org - see the comments)*.

In my case, I had to change the user of the query, table names (so that they match my event monitor name) and remove the condition "where as.UOW_ID=27".

Comment: The given link of db2commerce is not working now, can any one post the answer mentioned on the db2commerce.

Comment: It's available on archive.org - https://web.archive.org/web/20171222012657/http://db2commerce.com/2013/12/03/using-an-event-monitor-to-capture-statements-with-values-for-parameter-markers/

Comment: Solution from archive.org is no longer working.. - SQL0104N  An unexpected token "class" was found following "alter service"

Comment: It still works for me